# Django - SImple left join between 2 tables

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have been searching for `LEFT JOIN` of Django on Stackoverflow, however, most of solution are just too complicated.

My models:

```
class Voucher(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    delivery_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    start_at = models.DateTimeField()
    end_at = models.DateTimeField()
    discount_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    discount_amount = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)


class VoucherCustomer(models.Model):
    voucher_code = models.OneToOneField(Voucher, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='voucher_code', primary_key=True)
    customer_id = models.IntegerField()
    times_used = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This is what I tried:

```
from django.db.models.sql.datastructures import Join

#I thought this one is like 
            from VoucherCustomer left join Voucher  
            on VoucherCustomer.voucher_code = Voucher.code 

j=Join(VoucherCustomer, 'voucher_code', 
       Voucher,"LEFT JOIN" ,'code', True)  


j.objects.filter(voucher_code ='SAIGONS247').values('code', 'delivery_type', 'description', 'times_used').values
```

However, I got this result in the end:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_joining_columns'
```

Comment: if you already have One to One Field relation to Voucher, why would you need a Join? You can access your child field attribute you know? or you can do a Subquery to the other model to get the value you want.

Comment: I did not know about it, do you have any sources ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a ForeignKey or OneToOne Relationship, you can access the related object's attributes directly using double underscores.

```
j = VoucherCustomer.objects.filter(voucher_code__code ='SAIGONS247')
j.values('voucher_code__code', 'voucher_code__delivery_type', 'voucher_code__description', 'times_used')
```